# VBA - Insert data in different cells without interruption

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a worksheet, in this I would like to fill different cells by an input.

Currently it works by clicking in the cell. However, you have to click on each cell individually.

Now I want that when I confirm the input in the first cell, the input for the second value appears directly and so I can fill up to 5 values in a row without clicking each time.

So i click a button it should open a input dialog, there i insert my input, then it appears in the first cell, without closing it changes to second input dailog, where i insert my input again ....

Here my code of the currect solution.

I hope u understand and can help me with this function

````
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim varEintrag
    If Target.Cells(1).Address(0, 0) = "D12" Then
        varEintrag = Application.InputBox("Bitte Wert eintragen", "Dateneingabe")
        If varEintrag <> "Falsch" And varEintrag <> "False" Then
            If IsNumeric(varEintrag) Then
                Target = CDbl(varEintrag)
            Else
                Target = varEintrag
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub```
````

Comment: Then, since the event is triggered only if the selected cell is "D12", your code should place all the `inputBox` strings in an array and then placing it in the necessary range.

Comment: Will you be entering only numbers? The `If IsNumeric` is kind of confusing, I mean the `Else` part. Please do clarify.

Comment: @VBasic2008 No Not only numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Trigger Multiple Cells Entry

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const iAddress As String = "D12"
    Const mrgAddress As String = "D12,E12,D13,D15,E15"
    
    Dim iCell As Range
    
    Set iCell = Intersect(Range(iAddress), Target)
    If iCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim mrg As Range: Set mrg = Range(mrgAddress)
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim varEintrag As Variant
    
    For Each iCell In mrg.Cells
        
        varEintrag = Application.InputBox( _
            Prompt:="Bitte Wert in Zelle '" & iCell.Address(0, 0) _
                & "' eintragen:", _
            Title:="Dateneingabe", _
            Default:=iCell.Value)
    
        If varEintrag <> "Falsch" And varEintrag <> "False" Then
            If IsNumeric(varEintrag) Then
                iCell.Value = CDbl(varEintrag)
            Else
                iCell.Value = varEintrag
            End If
        Else
            Exit For ' Cancel
        End If
    
    Next iCell

SafeExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Comment: great solution, but in cell D13 it is a date. This is buggy and doesn´t work. For me it seems to add up the values i insert? The other cells are working great

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this modified event. It consecutively asks about the 5 necessary inputs and then place them in the necessary range:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim varEintrag, arrE(4), i As Long, k As Long
    If Target.Rows.count > 1 Or Target.Columns.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Target.cells(1).Address(0, 0) = "D12" Then
        Dim rngRet As Range: Set rngRet = Range("D12, E12, D13, D15, E15")
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrE)
            varEintrag = Application.InputBox("Bitte Wert eintragen " & i + 1, "Dateneingabe")
            If varEintrag <> "Falsch" And varEintrag <> "False" Then
                If IsNumeric(varEintrag) Then
                    arrE(k) = CDbl(varEintrag): k = k + 1
                Else
                    arrE(i) = varEintrag: k = k + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        Dim cel As Range: k = 0
        For Each cel In rngRet.cells
            cel.Value = arrE(k): k = k + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

This is a version iterating between each discontinuous range cells and ask for input in each such a cell **address**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows.count > 1 Or Target.Columns.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Target.cells(1).Address(0, 0) = "D12" Then
        Dim rngRet As Range: Set rngRet = Range("D12, E12, D13, D15, E15")
        Dim varEintrag, cel As Range
        For Each cel In rngRet.cells
            varEintrag = Application.InputBox("Bitte Wert eintragen in " & cel.Address, "Dateneingabe")
            If varEintrag <> "Falsch" And varEintrag <> "False" Then
                If IsNumeric(varEintrag) Then
                    cel.Value = CDbl(varEintrag)
                Else
                    cel.Value = varEintrag
                End If
            End If
        Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats a great solution, but the cells are not D12, 13, 14, 15. How can i insert into different Columns, like D12, E12, D13, D15, E15

Comment: @michi I will adapt the code to return per columns...

Comment: @michi Please, test the updated code.

Comment: thanks, but i dont understand what i need to change to insert the data in the cells i want to. @FaneDuru

Comment: @michi I cannot understand your question... Do you want clicking in a cell, fill in the `InputBox` and so on? If so, you should state in which range do you need the event to be triggered. If not, please better explain what you want accomplishing.

Comment: i want to fill into the cells D12, E12, D13, D15, E15

Comment: @michi OK. Now, you want proceeding as the above code does, meaning to firstly set the inputBox strings and then fill the cells in the range, or iterate between each cell in the range and ask for the appropriate input string?

Comment: @michi Please, test the updated code. It will proceed as the previous code but it will place the input strings in the range, you supply. It will do that due to the fact the iteration logic is the necessary one (by rows then by columns). If you will need a different random order, it is also possible but with a different approach. Iterating between all range cells and expressly ask for the input in that specific cell...

Comment: @michi Edited the code and also added a version able to deal with any cells order. But the user must be **attentive to the `InputBox` message, showing the cell address where the supplied string will be dropped**...

Comment: working fine right now :) thank you

Comment: @michi Which version did you try?

Comment: i prefer the last one, this is working fine

Comment: @michi OK. The first one (theoretically) should be faster for a large range of inputs, but not the case. It has the problem to iterate in its logic, not in the one you place in the range...